# Getting the thumbnail from a video inside the APK

Tags: android, video, thumbnails

I'm working on an app that includes a large number of videos inside the raw directory in the apk and need to generate thumbnails. I can't seem to get the path right though for the ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(path, KIND) also is there a better way than that?

Comment: What path have you tried?

Comment: a few "android.resource://packagename/raw/filename"

"file:///packagename/raw/filename"

"file:///packagename/res/raw/filename"

"/packagename/raw/filename"

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the AssetManager to get the raw asset path correct http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html

Consider doing something like:

```
String [] videos = getAssets.list("raw");
```

Then iterator through the array and call ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail on each file that is a video.

Comment: problem is I have around 100 videos and they are split into sub menus so I only need a few at a time

Comment: also this is happening in an arrayadapter spawned by a fragment.

Comment: also part of the problem is I need the path to files inside the apk "raw" returns nothing